# How to resolve issue with relative paths in python

Tags: python, file, directory, filesystems

I'm developing a package. I want to store some data in json files and retrieve this data within my package.

```
def get_contract_details(path: str) -> Tuple[str, list[str]]:
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        content = json.load(file)
        address = content['address']
        abi = content['abi']
        return address, abi


DETAILS = {
    'uniswap': get_contract_details('_contracts/uniswap_v2_router.json')
}


class Uniswap(BaseRouter):
    def __init__(self, provider: Web3, wallet: Wallet):
        address, abi = DETAILS['uniswap']
        super().__init__(provider, wallet, address, abi)
```

When I try to import class retrieving json data within package, I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '_contracts/uniswap_v2_router.json'
```

I'm guessing this problem related to relative paths. When I try to import the class, it tries to retrieve data from 'CURRENT_PATH/_contracts/uniswap_v2_router.json' rather than 'PACKAGE_PATH/_contracts/uniswap_v2_router.json'. How I can to resolve this issue and trouble-free store and retrieve this data?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to get the **absolute path** of your specific file.

```py
import os

path = '_contracts/uniswap_v2_router.json'
abs_path = os.path.abspath(path)
print(abs_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

There're two things you can try:

1. **Absolute Path**. You expect the json file to always be stored in the exact same file location. ***You expect the json file to be stored and/or generated in a FIXED directory outside of your package.***

```
DETAILS = {
    'uniswap': get_contract_details('full/path/to/uniswap_v2_router.json')
}
```

2. **Relative Path**. Your package may be deployed on other computers that do not follow the same path for the json file. ***You expect the json file to be stored and/or generated WITHIN your package's directory.***

   For this to work I'd need to understand your project's file structure. Essentially, use `..` for each parent directory.

   In the example below that'd mean your path is `../folder_1/uniswap_v2_router.json`

   ```
   project
       folder_1
           uniswap_v2_router.json
       src
           contract.py
   ```